# Clipping raster exactly to outline of shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, visualisation

I have clipped the shape I want but it looks messy with ragged edges. I want to remove these and have clean edges.

I have tried doing this on QGIS but have come to the conclusion that it is not possible. Hopefully I am wrong. I have access to QGIS, GIMP photo editor, paint , R and Python. Unfortunately I don't have ArcGIS where I believe it is easily possible.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can supersample the raster data, i.e. artificially decrease the pixel size (e.g. from 1000 m to 250 m), using a nearest neighbor resampling method and then clip the supersampled raster with your shapefile. The downside is that the size of your raster file is going to increase.

Comment: Thank you. I used GDAL warp (reproject) but can only seem to increase pixel size and not decrease. Is GDAL Warp (reproject) tool the correct tool?

Comment: In QGIS, right click the raster layer in the Layers panel and then select Export -> "Save as". There you can change the resolution as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is the messy appearance of the "ragged edges", it might make more sense to hide the raster where it falls outside the polygon. An easy way to do this is with an inverted polygon style.

1. Right click on your country outline layer > duplicate.
2. Change the style of the duplicate layer to **Inverted polygons**, with a white fill and stroke style = no pen.

[image]